# Most pythonic way to remove tuples from a list if first element is a duplicate

Tags: python, list, tuples

The code I have so far is pretty ugly:

```
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
previous_elem = []
unique_tuples = []
for tuple in orig:
    if tuple[0] not in previous_elem:
        unique_tuples += [tuple]
    previous_elem += [tuple[0]]
assert unique_tuples == [(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)]
```

There must be a more pythonic solution.

Comment: In the case of duplicates, do you just want it to return the first tuple found?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't care which tuple round you return for duplicates, you could always convert your list to a dictionary and back:

```
>>> orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
>>> list(dict(orig).items())
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

If you want to return the ***first*** tuple round, you could reverse your list twice and use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), like this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
>>> new = list(OrderedDict(orig[::-1]).items())[::-1]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

These are not the most efficient solutions (*if that's of great importance*) , but they do make for nice idiomatic one-liners.

---

## Some benchmarking

Note the difference in speed, and that should you not care which tuple round you return, the first option is much more efficient:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = '''
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer('(list(dict(orig).items()))', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.0015771419037069459
```

compared to

```
>>>setup = '''
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
from collections import OrderedDict
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer('(list(OrderedDict(orig[::-1]).items())[::-1])', 
             setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.024554947372323
```

The first option is nearly 15 times faster according to these speed tests.

That being said however, [Saksham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29612692/4686625) is also `O(n)` and smashes these dictionary methods efficiency wise:

```
>>> setup = '''
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
newlist = []
seen = set()
def fun():
    for (a, b) in orig:
        if not a in seen:
            newlist.append((a, b))
            seen.add(a)
    return newlist
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer('fun()', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
0.0004833390384996095
```

Comment: As I am ordering the tuples afterwards by the second item (thus only caring about duplicate first items), this is the best solution for my case. Reduced 8 loc to 1. Thanks!

Comment: I will also point out that `OrderedDict` comes from the `collections` module, which is built-in and it needs to be imported.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first containing a specific key to always be the one that appears in the final list:

```
list(reversed(collections.OrderedDict( reversed([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)])).items()))
```

Which results in:

```
 [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to store in an additional data structure, the time complexity `O(n^2)`, as pointed out in the comments:

```
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
newlist = []
for (a, b) in orig:
    if not any(x == a for x, y in newlist):
        newlist.append((a, b))
print newlist    # prints [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

A little book-keeping can reduce it to linear time:

```
orig = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)]
newlist = []
seen = set()
for (a, b) in orig:
    if not a in seen:
        newlist.append((a, b))
        seen.add(a)
print newlist    # prints [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: Your method will work, yes, but runs linear search for each element, which gives O(n²) complexity. Using `dict` however, adds extra memory consumption (not much), but makes it O(n) in ideal case

Comment: @myaut Agreed. The dictionary solution was already up. I should probably add the space-time tradeoff to my answer.

Comment: I could add a benchmark for the answers to mine if you'd like.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Sure please go ahead. I've also added another version that does a little book-keeping to reduce time complexity.

Comment: @SakshamVarma Added a benchmark to my answer, yours is the fastest :)